# Appengine org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException when makePersistent()

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus

I've this object:

```
@Entity
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Channel implements Serializable, Cacheable {



@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@Id
public Long id;

// NOTE THE PERSISTENT TAGS
@Persistent
private String name;

@Persistent
private boolean hotblocked = false;

........
```

When I run pm.makePersistent(c)  (pm is PersistenceManager), I got this:

```
An object of class "com.iuculano.tvitaliane.server.types.Channel" uses SingleFieldIdentity using the field "id" yet this field has not had its value set! Either set the field manually, or set a value-strategy for that field.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: An object of class "com.iuculano.tvitaliane.server.types.Channel" uses SingleFieldIdentity using the field "id" yet this field has not had its value set! Either set the field manually, or set a value-strategy for that field.
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.setIdentity(JDOStateManager.java:820)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2374)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.makePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2357)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1896)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectWork(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1745)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:731)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)
    at com.iuculano.tvitaliane.server.db.ChannelJDOWrapper.insertChannel(ChannelJDOWrapper.java:45)
    at com.iuculano.tvitaliane.server.scrapers.Import.caricaListaTvita(Import.java:101)
    at com.iuculano.tvitaliane.server.requests.InitialImport.doPost(InitialImport.java:23)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
18-feb-2013 16.07.53 com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.UrlFetchJob execute
```

I don't understand what does it means, I've valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY, where I'm wrong?

Comment: as per your comment I "noted" the @Persistent annotations, but then I would point out that they are totally unnecessary ... the vast majority of field types (String, int, boolean, etc) are all defaulted to being persistent, so much cleaner to leave those annotations out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution:

I've two problems:

1) Remove the @id annotation.
2) Remove @Entity

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Keys), you should forget the @id annotation.